# Почему "пять человек", а не "пять человеков"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, управление, количественно-именное-сочетание

Почему говорится "пять человек", а не "пять человеков"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В количественных сочетаниях (в именительном и винительном падежах) числительное **управляет родительным падежом существительног**о: пять девочек, пять мальчиков, но тогда почему "пять человек"? Где здесь управление родительным падежом?

Для ответа сравним **следующие сочетания**:  пять столов, пять домов, но: пять килограмм, пять ампер. Существительные мужского рода в родительном падеже кроме основного окончания ОВ могут иметь **вариантное нулевое окончание, совпадающее с начальной формой существительного.**

Именно эта особенность использована в сочетании "пять человек". Хотя сущ. "человек" не имеет форм множественного числа (человеки, человеками), но в данном случае **начальная форма "человек" заменяет форму родительного падежа с нулевым окончанием.**

Answer (score 0):

Как склонять числительное сто и двести в творительном и предложном:
ста? дать кушать ста пяти человекам, говорить о двуХстах человеках? о ста человеках?
Екатерина
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Верно: *ста пятидесяти человекам, ста пятьюдесятью человеками, о ста пятидесяти человеках; двумстам человекам, двумястами человеками, о двухстах человеках*.

Правильно ли выражение: "В Океании затонул паром со 117 человеками на борту"?
Спасибо. greenjay
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Фраза корректна.

Answer (score 0):

Большой толковый словарь:
[**ЧЕЛОВЕК**](http://m.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA&all=x), -а; *мн.* люди, -ей и (*устар. и шутл.*) человеки, -ов; м. (**с колич. сл. только косв. мн.: человек, человекам, человеками, о человеках**).

[Пояснение: **человек (Р. п.)**, человекам (Д. п.), человеками (Т. п.), о человеках (П. п.); именительный и винительный падежи множественного числа НЕ используются.]

При числительном **пять** (т. е. в И. и В. падежах) существительное (и одушевленное, и неодушевленное) **ставится в родительном падеже множественного числа**:
пять книг, пять дней, пять лыжников, пять человек.

Количественные числительные в этом случае вместе с именем существительным образуют единое словосочетание, выступающее в роли одного члена предложения.

*В комнате находятся **пять человек*** (подлежащее).
*Мы увидели **пять человек*** (дополнение).

[Сочетания количественных числительных с именами существительными](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/106-sochetaniya-kolichestvennyih-chislitelnyih-69172.html)